# Como guardar en un array números de un .txt pasando el fichero a través de un método?

Tags: java, array, archivo, lógica

Saludos quiero mejorar mi capacidad de entender el tema de los métodos normalmente sueles ver ejemplos más sencillos pero encontré un ejercicio que me hace pensar como resolverlo.
El ejercicio consiste en leer un fichero txt y guardar esos números en un array Por ejemplo tengo un Fichero y en el pongo los siguientes números=1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Estos números están separados por espacios en blanco y por comas y al fichero le pongo de nombre numeros.txt. Ahora el ejercicio me pide aplicar este método
int[] numeros = LeeNumerosFichero(File f);

De aquí deduzco que quiere que le pase por parámetro el Fichero y que se guarden en un array de enteros pero no logro verlo claro. Es muy confuso porque hay muchas clases para leer ficheros y no se cual utilizar.

1.En el bucle while como puedo agregar esos números?

2.Como puedo quitarle las comas y los espacios?

3.Me encuentro con este error  first type:  int[]  second type: int

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file;
        try {
            file = new File("prueba.txt");

            int[] numeros = LeeNumerosFichero(file);
            for(int i=0;i<numeros.length;i++){
                System.out.println("numeros:"+numeros[i]);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static int[] LeeNumerosFichero(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
        String s1 = "";

        while (scan.hasNext()) {

            s1 += scan.nextLine();

        }
        String[] arrayString = s1.split(", ");//1, 2, 3, 4
        int[] numeros = new int[arrayString.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            numeros[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrayString[i]);
        }

        return numeros;
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: numero es un array.. como agregas items a un array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te lanza error debido a que en este apartado,estas queriendo sumar un array con el cast del string,para agregar números en el array debes iterar con un bucle for o while...ademas de conocer el tamaño que tendrá el array

```
numeros+=Integer.parseInt(s1);
```

lo que haces acá es concatenar el string s1 con los numero leídos en el cual obtendrás que s1 =1, 2, 3, 4 no podrás hacer el cast de esa manera

```
 s1+=scan.nextLine();
```

Una idea es que podes hacer uso del método `split()` el cual te permite fragmentar una cadena en base a una expresión como dices que tus numeros estan separados por coma y espacio `(, )` este método te devolverá un `array` de tipo `String` solo con los valores separados por esa expresión,ahora realizas el cast correspondiente,puedes hacer uso de un bucle o Stream()

```
public static int[]  LeeNumerosFichero(File f) throws FileNotFoundException{
    
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(f);
    String s1=""; 
     
     while(scan.hasNext()){
       
         s1+=scan.nextLine();                  
     }
String[]arrayString=s1.split(", ");//1, 2, 3, 4
int[]numeros=new int[arrayString.length];

for (int i=0;i<numeros.length;i++ ) {
    numeros[i]=Integer.parseInt(arrayString[i]);
}  
  
    return numeros;
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137366/discussion-on-answer-by-dramaturgo-como-guardar-en-un-array-numeros-de-un-txt-p).